# Properties file mechanism in jclouds?

Tags: jclouds

Does jclouds have any mechanism where properties in org.jclouds.Constants can be overridden using "properties" files? Properties can be set in code, but that is not usefull if you are using jclouds through jclouds-cli.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide properties via ContextBuilder.overrides:

```java
Properties properties = new Properties();
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(...))) {
    properties.load(is);
}

BlobStoreContext blobStoreContext = ContextBuilder
    .newBuilder(BLOBSTORE_TYPE)
    .credentials(IDENTITY, CREDENTIAL)
    .overrides(properties)
    .build();
```